# writing myself strncat, unable to enlarge the size of the array C

Tags: c, arrays

as far as I'm concerned, strncat enlarges the size of the array you want to cat.
for example:

```
char str1[] = "This is str1";
char str2[] = "This is str2";
```

and here the length of str1 is 12 and str2 is also 12, but when I strncat them, str1 changes from 12 to 24.
I was asked to write strncat by my own, but I can't figure out how to enlarge the size of an array, taking in account that we didn't learn pointers yet.

I tried just putting every char in the end of the array while moving the distance by 1 each iteration, but as you would have thought, it doesn't put the data in the array because there is no such position like this in the array (str[20] when str's length is 10 for example).

Thanks in advance,
every help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*strncat enlarges the size of the array you want to cat.*", no, it doesn't. You observe the effects of [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior#t=201701211003395288186), when `strcat`ing past the end of the array.

Comment: "*I can't figure out how to enlarge the size of an array, taking in account that we didn't learn pointers*" so then you are stuck and need to wait until you learned about pointers.

Comment: If so, how come that when you cat str1(length 5) and str2(length 10), str1 becomes str1(length15)?

Comment: "so then you are stuck and need to wait until you learned about pointers.", we got this as homework while they know we don't have any clue about pointers. There should be some way that I can't figure out why I am making this complicated.

Comment: This is just by bad luck. The call writes past the end of `str1`, which could also just have made the program crash.

Comment: Ok, then can you explain to me how strncat works? If it does not enlarge the array, how is it getting bigger?

Comment: It is not getting bigger. You mistakenly think it is getting bigger.

Comment: @kubyxino Check my answer I hope you will find that useful.

Comment: @M.M Again, so what does it do to cat both strings?

Comment: Is your homework to concatenate C-strings? Or is your homework *explicitly about resizing* the arrays used to hold them? The former does not *necessarily* include the latter,

Comment: `strlen` returns the length of the string, that is, counts until the first null character. It does NOT return the size of the memory allocated for `str1`!

Comment: @alk my homework is to concatenate c-strings.

Comment: You probably need to understand that in C a "string" isn't a data type (like `int` or `double`) but a concept.

Comment: "*my homework is to concatenate*" then just provide a large enough destination "buffer" to concatenate to. Take care to not write past the end of the "buffer".

Comment: The `strncat` function takes two parameters, both pointers. If you don't understand pointers, you *can't* understand `strncat`. It's a show stopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strlen` returns the length of the string, that is, counts until the first null character. It does NOT return the size of the memory allocated for `str1`!

When you concatenate`str2` to `str1`, you write beyond the memory allocated for `str1`. That will cause undefined behavior. In your particular case, it seems nothing happens and it even seems that `str1` has become larger. That is not so. However (in your paticular case), if `str2` follows `str1` in memory, you just overwrote `str2`. Try printing `str2`. It will probaby print `his is str2`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `strcat()` et al. does not enlarge a buffer, your implementation does not have to do it. (And it is simply not possible with the parameter list of `strcat()`.) It is the *caller's responsibility* to pass a destination buffer big enough.

On the *caller's side* you can simply create an array big enough and pass its address. However, you can still use variable length arrays (VLA):

```
char str1[] = "This is str1";
char str2[] = "This is str2";
char str1str2[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1];

strcpy( str1str2, str1 );
yourstrcat( str1str2, str2 );
```

`str1str2` is big enough to store both contents plus 1 for the string terminator `\0`.

Comment: It might  be worth mentioning that VLA's are available from C99 on only and became optional with C11.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, I solved the problem. As some of you said, I don't need to enlarge the string, I just need to make sure it's big enough to contain all the data.
what I did eventually is this:

```
void strnCat(char dest[], char src[], int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    int len = strlen(dest);
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        dest[len+i] = src[i];
        dest[len+i+1] = 0;
    }
}
```

so my main problem was that I forget to add the null at the end of the array to make it a string and that I used strlen(str) instead of saving the length in a variable. I did that because I forgot that there is no end of the string after the null disappears.

Comment: All those `int`s really should be `size_t`s. Mind the type returned by `strlen()`.

Comment: You don't need this `dest[len+i+1] = 0;` *inside* the loop.

Comment: Also the code shown does not test for the termination (the "end") of `src`. This allows to read past the end of `src`, which invoked the infamouse undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

It is a really strange task to let students implement `strncat`, since this is one of the C functions that is very difficult to use correctly.

So to implement it yourself, you should read its specification in the C standard or in the POSIX standard. There you will find that `strncat` doesn't enlarge any array. By the way, arrays cannot be enlarged in C at all, it's impossible by definition. Note the careful distinction between the words *array* (can contain arbitrary bytes) and *string* (must contain one null byte) in the standard wording.

A saner alternative to implement is `strlcat`, which is not in the C standard but also widely known.

Comment: @Rolandlllig can't we enlarge an array using realloc?

Comment: @VenuKantSahu only if the array was initially allocated

Comment: @VenuKantSahu No, since realloc doesn't operate on arrays but on untyped memory. Furthermore the question clearly states that they haven't yet covered pointers.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying

Comment: Even you could do that, it would be impossible to return the pointer, because in such a case the destination parameter has to be `char **`.